# One to Many Mapping Persist Collection

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I need some help, I'm trying to create a system, but i have a problem to persist dice, so what i want is:

i have two tables are they: Project and Products

in Project i want to persist a collection of products, but i dont need products know what projects are they linked, so its like One To Many unidirectional Relation.

i want to know how can i map this in the database(Postgres) and Hibernate, and how can i make the PostMapping.

**Tables in data Base**

```
create table if not exists produto(
id_produto bigserial not null,
codigo varchar(20) not null,
nomenclatura varchar(60) not null,
preco numeric(5,2),
aplicacao varchar(60),
dosagem decimal(5,2),
inspiracao varchar(60),
amostra varchar(10),
constraint pk_produto primary key(id_produto));

create table if not exists projeto (
id_projeto bigserial not null,
id_cliente bigint not null,
id_produto bigint,

data_criacao timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
ra bigserial not null,
situacao varchar(20),

constraint pk_projeto primary key(id_projeto, ra),

constraint fk_projeto_cliente foreign key(id_cliente) 
references cliente(id_cliente) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

constraint fk_projeto_produto foreign key(id_produto)
references produto(id_produto) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

**Model Class Project**

```
@Entity
@Data
@IdClass(ProjetoId.class)
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "projeto", schema = "public")
public class Projeto {

@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PRO_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="PRO_SEQ", sequenceName="PROJETO_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
@Column(name = "id_projeto")
private Long idProjeto;

@Valid
@ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = ValidationGroups.ClienteId.class)
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Cliente cliente;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_produto", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();

@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PRO_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="PRO_SEQ", sequenceName="PROJETO_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
@Column(name = "ra")
private Long ra;

@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "situacao")
private StatusProjeto situacao;

@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
@Column(name = "data_criacao")
private LocalDate dataRegistro;

public void finalizar() {
    if(naoPodeSerFinalizado()) {
        throw new ProjetoException("Projeto não pode ser finalizado");
    }
    setSituacao(StatusProjeto.APROVADO);
}

public void cancelar() {
    if(naoPodeSerFinalizado()) {
        throw new ProjetoException("Projeto não pode ser cancelado");
    }
    setSituacao(StatusProjeto.RECUSADO);
}

public boolean podeSerFinalizado() {
    return StatusProjeto.PEDENTE.equals(getSituacao());
}

public boolean naoPodeSerFinalizado() {
    return !podeSerFinalizado();
}
```

}

**Model Class Product**

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "produto",schema = "public")
public class Produto {

@Id
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_produto")
private Long idProduto;

@NotBlank
@Column(name ="codigo")
@Size(max = 60)
private String codigo;

@NotBlank
@Size(max = 60)
@Column(name = "nomenclatura")
private String nomenclatura;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "preco")
private Double preco;

@Size(max = 60)
@Column(name = "aplicacao")
private String aplicacao;

@DecimalMin(value = "0.00")
@Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 2)
@Column(name = "dosagem")
private Double dosagem;

@Size(max = 60)
@Column(name = "inspiracao")
private String inspiracao;

@Size(max = 10)
@Column(name = "amostra")
private String amostra;
```

}

**Error**

```
A Foreign key refering com.ciasense.apiciasense.model.Projeto from com.ciasense.apiciasense.model.Produto has the wrong number of column. should be 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key column cannot be the same as an existing column.

In this case, renaming the primary key `idProduto` and column name `id_produto`, in the class Produto to `id` should resolve it. As it is, the context of id is bound within the Produto class so it need not be mentioned in the name.